# How to access emp table in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

When I execute `select * from emp` SQL*Plus hangs even I logged in through run as administrator also.

But when I do `desc emp` and when I insert a record and `select count(*) from emp`  it works fine.

Comment: Post result of `select owner, object_name from all_objects where object_name='EMP';`

Comment: Can you explain more detail about "it is not responding"? Is there any error message??

Comment: When I execute select * from emp I am not getting any error message nothing is coming means it become hang.

Comment: Post what I asked. And, how are you executing the query, SQL*Plus or any GUI based client tool?

Comment: In SQL*Plus I am executing the query select * from emp;

Comment: when I am executing any other table like dept,salgrade or my own created tables then it works fine but only emp table getting problem.

Comment: take a screenshot of your sqlplus screen and update your question, that would provide clarity on what you actually mean by "not responding"

Comment: Try a `;` at the end of your select statement: `select * from emp;` without it SQL*Plus is waiting for you to complete the statement.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of oracle error during the execution of creation of the table.

Try droping the table and creating  the table.

```
delete from emp;
drop table emp;
```

After that create the table again.